# UIPanGestureRecognizer distance

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to change the distance of the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` before it will trigger?, the current implementation seems to have a distance margin of 5-10pixels before it is triggered, I would like to lower it if possible.

The reason is I use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in combination with the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` to change the rotation of a object, with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` because of the distance margin it will not rotate right away and therefore the first rotation update will not be smooth (because it will go from 0 to something like 5degrees)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does not have any extra settings available on it. You could, however, write a [custom gesture recognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2) to do this.